# Cant fix: The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, dependencies, elementary-os, mono

I was trying to completely remove mono since it breaks my ability to apt-get upgrade.

When I try:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 5.0.0.100) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 5.0.0.100) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 5.0.0.100) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
 libmono-system-web4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 5.0.0.100) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
 libmono-system4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 5.0.0.100) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
                         Recommends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.0.0.100-0xamarin4+debian7b1) but 4.8.0.495-0xamarin1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When i try to remove any of the packages below via:

```
sudo dpkg -r libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil
```

Then i get this error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil:
 libmono-i18n4.0-all depends on libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil (= 5.0.0.100-0xamarin4+debian7b1).

dpkg: error processing package libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the packages higher up the dependency tree? It looks like the meta-package for Mono on Debian-derived systems would be mono-devel or mono-complete. http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` try to do? Or `sudo apt-get remove libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil` (etc.)

Comment: @bgvaughan, yes both of those packages removed succesfully

Comment: @derobert both of those commands gives me the same error as dpkg

Comment: @schmoopy which command does—there were two. Also, I'm pretty sure apt-get can't print out 'dpkg: dependency…' so it gave a different error—but maybe saying the same thing? Can you remove libmono-i18n4.0-all? Normally apt-get will chase up the chain for you... do you maybe have a held package?

Comment: @derobert, OHH actually, the error i get form the 2 apt-get commands is the first one mentioned in my post

Comment: @schmoopy well, I guess you could try chasing the dependency chain by hand and `dpkg -r  libmono-i18n4.0-all`. But I'm surprised about `apt-get dist-upgrade` giving the same error. That's weird.

Comment: @derobert Yea that is what i was hoping that I could get around, but i'll proceed with that if i dont get an answer soon.  Yes it is so odd and unfortunate that this error breaks my upgrade'ability too.